# unity cannot load scene(already added to build settings)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these scenes

[image]

I want to unload the menu and to load `magicValley`

```
public void startGame()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadScene("Menu", "MagicValley"));
}
public IEnumerator loadScene(string from, string to)
{
    yield return SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(from);
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(to,LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(to));
    resetManager(to);
}
```

The menu unloaded correctly, but I can't load `MagicValley`, did I miss something?

I try to output the scene name like this

```
Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("MagicValley").name);
Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(2).name);
```

but just ouputs `null`, it seems only can output loaded scenes, does it matter?

Comment: are you unloading the scene this is on then expect the next line to run to load the new one?

Comment: [`GetSceneByName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByName.html) => Searches through the Scenes **loaded** for a Scene with the given name ... same for [`GetSceneByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html) so yeah might be a timing issue ... a bit dirty but you could try to put a `yield return new WaitUntil(() => SceneManager.GetSceneByName("MagicValley").IsValid());` and check if it every finishes

Comment: very good point @BugFinder

Comment: Did you check the sence have been load correctly? Since `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` will not wait until scene is loaded but directly passed, and you just use one `yield return` to skip a frame, which cause the following operation to be failed.

Comment: Thank you~ I found the issue, I tried to unload the menu scene with a button in the menu scene, which seems to cause it to never done. so it will never excute next code.I'll just put the ui in another scene. But is there any way to unload scene of it self?

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found the issue with follow code,

```
AsyncOperation ao = SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(from);
while (!ao.isDone)
{
    yield return null;
    Debug.Log(ao.progress);
}
```

I tried to unload the menu scene with a button in the menu scene, which seems to cause it to never done. so it will never excute next code.

I'll just put the ui in the gamemanager scene. But is there any way to unload scene of it self?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding another question as an answer.